# Music player playlist logic

Tags: javascript, audio, playlist

I'm creating a small music player web app, everything works fine, I have a problem:

I want to create a playlist for it too and I'm kind of beginner in JS and I don't know how to create the logic for that (every time user click on a specific song title in playlist, play that exact song which he just clicked)I stored songs in a Array

**Source code:** https://yun.ir/qnrk56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this behaviour in different ways.

This is what I tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/2qc0kwbg/

I added a function called `setSong()` which accepts a parameter called `number` and sets the song to that number (code logic copied from `prevSong()` and `nextSong()`). I added to every HTML element with the class `.player__song` the `onclick` attribute with the value of `setSong(<index>)` where <index> is the index of the song in the array.

The setSong() function looks like this:

```
function setSong(number){
  currentSong = number
  showSong()
  audio.play()
  changeBgBody()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component,useRef, setStatus, status } from 'react';
import ‘./Song.css';

import song1 from "./music/song1.mp3";
import song2 from "./music/song2.mp3"
import song3 from "./music/song3.mp3"
import song4 from "./music/song4.mp3"

export default function MusicPlayer() {
    const data = [
        { imgSrc: ‘song1.png', audioSrc: song1},
        { imgSrc: ‘song2.png', audioSrc: song2},
        { imgSrc: ‘song3.png', audioSrc: song3},
        { imgSrc: ‘song4.png', audioSrc: song4},
    ];

    return (
        <div className=‘MusicPlayer>
            <ol>
            
                {data.map(({ imgSrc, audioSrc}) => (
                    <MediaComponent imgSrc={imgSrc} audioSrc={audioSrc}   />
                ))}
            </ol>
        </div>
    );
  
}

const MediaComponent = ({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => {
    const audioRef = useRef(null);
    const toggleAudio = () =>
      audioRef.current === null
        ? console.log("Audio component is not loaded yet.")
        : audioRef.current.paused
        ? audioRef.current.play()
        : audioRef.current.pause();

        
    return (
        <li>
            <img src={imgSrc} onClick={toggleAudio} />
            
            <audio
                ref={audioRef}
                src={audioSrc}
                onLoad={() => setStatus({ ...status, isLoaded: true })}
                onPlay={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: true })}
                onPause={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: false })}
                onError={() => setStatus({ ...status, error: true })}
            />
        </li>
    );
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).